# How to get a map of repeated values in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, mapping

I have a data frame with several duplicated values, as follow:

```
df = data.frame(position = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), names = c('AAA','BBB','CCC','BBB','AAA','DDD','AAA'))
```

I would like to get a new data frame with a mapping of the duplicated values such as:

```
new_df = data.frame(column1 = c(1,1,5,2), column2 = c(5,7,7,4))
```

I have tried the code below, but it only mapped based on the first position, I would like all of them.

```
df['pos'] = data.frame(position = match(df$`names`, unique(df$`names`)))
df = df %>%  select(., position, pos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base R you could do something like:

```
t(do.call(cbind,tapply(df$position,df$names,function(x)if(length(x)>1)combn(x,2))))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    1    7
[3,]    5    7
[4,]    2    4
```